# Searchable DropDownList in MVC ASP.Net using CHOSEN

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

My DROPDOWNLIST is not searchable, it is normal dropdownlist. You can see my view of create on the image. I used chosen plugin. I added css and js files to _Layout. Does it require any function?

Create.cshtml

```
 @model StockControl.Models.EntityFramework.IncomingProduct

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Add new product</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.materialId, "Material Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("materialId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.materialId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
            </div>
        </div>
}   
    @section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".chosen").chosen();
        });
    </script>
    }
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>_Layout</title>
        <link href="~/Content/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_Navbar")
    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
    <script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[View of create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tDxE.png)

Thanks in advance.

[Errors(At create 109 is  $(function () {](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMjHT.png)

Comment: Check this example: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Searchable-DropDownList-in-ASP-Net-MVC-with-Code-Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `chosen` class like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("materialId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen" })
```

Also, ensure that you have `chosen` plugin referenced in Layout.cshtml. Check for any javascript errors using browser Developer tools by pressing F12 key on the browser and then refreshing the page

**Update**

Include jquery and chosen plugin references before the `RenderSection("scripts")`

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
 @RenderSection("scripts", false)
```

Comment: Have you checked the Developer tools for any errors? Also, inspect the dropdown html to ensure that `chosen` css class is rendered.

Comment: `$("#chosen").chosen();` should be `$(".chosen").chosen();` since you have added `chosen` class on dropdown not id.

Comment: I updated but still not working. I also added errors in my question when I click to F12

Comment: The error `$ is not defined` can be caused due to missing jquery library or due to jquery libraries references causing conflict. I noticed that in your `_Layout.cshtmt` you don't have jQuery library reference so include that. Check updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much!! Done.